# Flipping UIView inside UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiview

In photo app of iphone you can see smooth scrolling to the other picture with finger flicking. Is it possible to allow individual view to be 'flipped' (or rotated) to show its back side ? Found that UIScrollView is used for smooth scrolling and found the code for flipping UI. Outside of UISCrollView I got the flip to work using the code below. But once inside UIScrollView this doesn't work - it executes but UI never switches.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:myView cache:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[myView exchangeSubviewAtIndex:0 withSubviewAtIndex:1];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Perhaps this is not suppose to work this way. What is the recommended way or technique to have flippable individual views inside the UIScrollView ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. It does work. Once inside UIScrollView there were several UIViews and I needed to make sure I grab the pointer to current UIView. The above code works in this case as well. I was doing a flip on a view which was hidden :)